# MySql query to compare data between two dates. Issue with 9/30 to 10/01?

Tags: mysql

Here's the query:

```
Select a.Date as Date, count(0) as Count(*) from mytable
where (not(exists(select 1 from mytable b where ((a.ID = b.ID) and (b.Date = a.Date+1))))) Group by a.Date
```

So everything works fine except for the transistion from `9/30/16` to `10/01/16`
In that case, for some strange reason it returns ALL of the IDs for `9/30/16` instead of just the ones that have disappeared from the table on `10/01/16`.
I have confirmed there is data in `10/01/16`.

Comment: `count(0) as Count(*)` is a syntax error. It should be `count(*) as Count`.

Comment: i created a View with the proper syntax.  the view works fine.  when I typed Show Create View myview to type the code into this question....  that's what was shown.

Comment: I'll bet it had backticks around `Count(*)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `a.Date+1` to get the next date, use `DATE_ADD(a.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`. When you use arithmetic, it first converts the date to a number, then performs arithmetic on the number. So `9/30/16` becomes `20160930`, and `+1` results in `20160931`. Since this isn't equal to `10/01/16`, none of the rows are considered to match. This will happen at the end of every month.

```
Select a.Date as Date, count(*) as Count 
from mytable a where (not(exists(
    select 1 from mytable b 
    where a.ID = b.ID and b.Date = date_add(a.Date, interval 1 day))))
Group by a.Date;
```

I discovered this by adding `a.Date+1` to the `select` clause to see what it was comparing with, and it printed:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| Date       | a.Date+1 | count |
+------------+----------+-------+
| 2016-09-30 | 20160931 |     1 |
| 2016-10-01 | 20161002 |     2 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: beautiful.  this is perfect.  Thank you